# Can chronic prostatitis be a risk factor of prostate cancer for patients?

Tags: cancer, prostate

I have learned from the internet that chronic prostatitis can last for a long time without cure, can this disease arise prostate cancer to patients?

Comment: There has no evidence showing that chronic prostatitis may cause prostate cancer.

Answer (score 2):

Since inflammation has been shown to be linked to cancer this had been investigated.

> RESULTS: The relative odds of prostate cancer were elevated in men with history of any type of prostatitis (odds ratio [OR] = 1.7; 95% confidence interval [CI] = 1.1-2.6) or acute prostatitis (2.5; 1.3-4.7). The mean time from most recent episode of acute prostatitis to the diagnosis of prostate cancer was 12.2 years. After exclusion of men with acute prostatitis 2 years before the index date, the relationship was somewhat reduced (1.9; 0.9-3.8). Chronic bacterial prostatitis was more weakly associated with prostate cancer (1.6; 0.8-3.1), whereas chronic pelvic pain syndrome was not associated at all (0.9; 0.4-1.8).
>
> CONCLUSIONS: Infection in the form of acute or chronic bacterial prostatitis may be associated with prostate cancer. However, our data do not provide compelling evidence to support this. As a result of the limitations of current methods of assessing chronic prostatitis, biochemical or tissue markers of infection or inflammation of the prostate may help clarify their role in the pathogenesis of prostate cancer.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/14712152/

The known associations are linked [here](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/prostate-cancer/causes/)

Comment: Nicely explained  +1